# TypeError: Cannot read property after refresh or after manipulation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, next.js

I am getting the following error after a refresh and sometimes on initial project run:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'statements' of undefined

This is really confusing because the data is rendering fine it just seems the connection fails. Any idea what may be causing the error?

There are no additional errors when I remove the `statements.map`

I used this medium article to get everything up and running: [Medium Article](https://medium.com/@tomanagle/create-a-server-side-rendering-graphql-client-with-next-js-and-apollo-client-acd397f70c64)

index.js:

```
import React, { useState, useReducer } from 'react'
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/react-hooks'

// Custom layout
import Layout from "../components/layout"

import '../sass/styles.scss'

// Data Query
import STATEMENTS_QUERY from '../graphql/statements'

function StatementCall(context) {

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(STATEMENTS_QUERY, {});

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row spaces">
          <div className="col-md-12">
            <p>Testing</p>
            {data.statements.data.map((statement, index) => (
              <div>
                <p>{statement.id}</p>
                <p>{statement.title}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default StatementCall
```

graphql/statements.js:

```
import gql from 'graphql-tag';

const STATEMENTS_QUERY = gql`
  query {
      statements(filter: {destination: 1991}) {
        data {
          id
          title
          body
        }
      }
    }
`;

export default STATEMENTS_QUERY;
```

Comment: that may be because api is not returning data

Comment: You could check if the results are loading, before you try to render them, e.g. `if (loading) return <p>Loading ...</p>;` [From the useQuery docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/#example)

Comment: @segFault Its funny I added this to the function and its working now and it doesn't break when I refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if the results are loading, before you try to render them.

Example:

```
function StatementCall(context) {

  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(STATEMENTS_QUERY, {});

  if (loading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  if (error) {
    // Handle error?
    return <p>{error}</p>;
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row spaces">
          <div className="col-md-12">
            <p>Testing</p>
            {data.statements.data.map((statement, index) => (
              <div>
                <p>{statement.id}</p>
                <p>{statement.title}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Check the [example in useQuery docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hooks/#example).

Comment: I think an issue with this approach would be that what would it display when it -is- loading? Maybe an || (<>Foo</>) structure at the end to display just in case would fix it. Also, maybe instead of checking loading, maybe a simpler approach would be {data.statements && data.statements.data.map(... so it would simply not display any data after the Testing tag.